# iOS: Fill a path larger than CGContext

Tags: ios, graphics, path, cgcontext, cgpath

I am working on a program that fills CGPath's on tiles in a tile map. The paths are sometimes larger than the tiles or extend beyond tile bounds. When drawing a tile, the program does filter out paths that are completely outside of a tile.

Is there wasted processing when a path is filled outside of a context bounds or does the CGContextFillPath(theContext) method account for this? I have been working on a clipping algorithm to split paths for the tiles, but I am not sure if this is necessary.

Any help is appreciated.
Oscar